# EF Code First doesn't see all migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my project I have dozen+ migrations. http://screencast.com/t/CA2kZk3WCFj
But when I try to create database from scratch EF only starts from the marked migration to the bottom.

if I enter command:
update-database -targetMigration InitialCreate
this is the response:
he specified target migration 'InitialCreate' does not exist. Ensure that target migration refers to an existing migration id.

How can I resolve this issue and make EF see all of the migrations?

Comment: Another solution could be to exclude all the migration class files from your project, and then adding a new migration, while targeting the new DB, thus scaffolding a new migration, which contains all of the changes.

Comment: Unfortunately we have multiple running environments, production for example is not running on latest migration. Also there are some custom scripts that would be a pain to collect and merge in new migration.

Comment: Check that your migrations are in the correct namespace

Comment: I can't really test this anymore :). Fixed by recreating migrations from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
In my case, the "ignored" migrations were not in the same namespace (caused by a project renamed).

Comment: This was the same cause for me, but when I tried renaming the namespace for each migration it didn't help.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60457128/2747593) pointed me in the direction of the `*.Designer.cs` files, which I discovered *also* needed to have their namespace adjusted.  (Designer files can be found by clicking arrow next to each migration in VS.)  Once I fixed the namespaces there, the migrations were picked up and applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This can often happen if you use the Update-Database command in Release mode. Running in Debug mode seems to work ok.

Comment: I don't have this issue anymore, if somebody else can confirm this I will gladly mark it as an answer...