# EF Core "no migrations found" despite Migrations folder containing migration files

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

We have a .NET Core project set up with a Migrations folder containing several migrations that we were able to successfully run in our Development database in the past by executing `dotnet ef database update`. However, we are now trying to apply those changes to our Staging database and it isn't working. We've set our `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` env variable to `Staging` and when we attempt to run the migrations, it seems like it is targeting Staging properly. A `dbo.__EFMigrationsHistory` table is created in our Staging database, but there are no entries in it. Also, when we run `dotnet ef migrations list`, we get a message that says "No migrations were found." Even if we set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable back to `Development`, we get the same result.

We've run all the above `dotnet ef` commands with the verbose flag and haven't gotten any errors. The only output that seems like it could be suspicious is `No referenced design-time services were found` and `No design-time services were found`, but we weren't able to determine what we need to do to fix these issues.

When we run `dotnet ef migrations add <migration name>`, it successfully generates a migration file in the Migrations folder, and when we run `dotnet ef migrations list` that new migration shows up, so it seems like our older migrations are in the correct place. They just aren't being detected by `dotnet ef` for some reason.

We have the following packages in our `.csproj`:

```
    <PackageReference Include="FlexLabs.EntityFrameworkCore.Upsert" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.2.0-beta.113">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.0" />
```

Any thoughts on why we can't get our existing migrations to run?

Comment: Did you run `dotnet ef database update` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out this error was because of the lack of Designer.cs files. We deleted them due to [the response in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048721/entity-framework-core-is-it-safe-to-delete-migration-designer-cs-if-we-will-nev/47060795#47060795), but EF was not able to find our migrations without them. If you plan on running your migrations in any other environments, don't delete your Designer files!

Comment: I believe that answer was for EF6 on .Net Framework, not ef-core.

Comment: No way.  I just ran into this on EF Core, .NET 6.  Hey MSFT, why did you design it this way? This is dumb.

Comment: I have run into this issue right now and I did not delete those designer files. after running add-migration command; the migration does not show in the folder - however it does exist on the disc.