# Entity Framework Core - No design-time services were found

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a pretty basic migration file. I'm executing `dotnet ef database update --verbose` in the Package Manager Console window and nothing is getting generated in SQL Server.

The final lines of output in the Package Manager Console window is shown below:

```
Finding design-time services for provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer...
Using design-time services from provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly BM.Server.
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly BM.Server...
No design-time services were found.
Done.
```

Here is what my code looks like and adding and removing migrations work. It's just trying to update the database that I am having this issue.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<BMDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BMDbConnectionString")));
    }
}

public class BMDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BMDbContext(DbContextOptions<BMDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

I also have the following nuget packages installed for the project and both dlls are in my bin directory:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Comment: Please, refer to this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation and create a design time dbcontext

Comment: @SergeyAnisimov It looks like i have everything in the link you provided. I have updated my post to show my code. Thanks.

Comment: you DON'T have to have a factory. It may have been that your command was targeting the wrong project and it couldn't find what it needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As referenced in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation) you should add the design time DbContext. Add the following class to your project:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

namespace WebApplication8
{
    public class DesignTimeBMDbContext : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BMDbContext>
    {
        public BMDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BMDbContext>();
            // pass your design time connection string here
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("<connection_string>");
            return new BMDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

After adding this class, EF CLI will use it for design time database creation and updates

Comment: Please note, that namespace should match with the namespace of your project

Comment: in 2022 u saved a chicken and the egg situation thanks

Comment: In my case somehow the <migration_name>.Designer.cs files got deleted and this also caused the behaviour described above. Solution found in this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/60457128/10656634](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60457128/10656634)